# How to add additional .m4a plugin to gstreamer1.0-plugins-*?

Tags: 20.04, sound, plugins, gstreamer, audio-recording

In the app. called Audio Recorder, I can't record in `.m4a` format. The app says,

> "Please install additional plugins(from gstreamer1.0-plugins-*
> package) to support the m4a format"

How do I do this?

Ubuntu 20.04,

**Preinstalled apps:**

```
$ sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ubuntu-restricted-extras is already the newest version (67).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
$ dpkg -l | grep gstreamer
    ii  gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0:amd64                 1.16.2-2                                          amd64        GObject introspection data for the GStreamer library
    ii  gstreamer1.0-alsa:amd64                    1.16.2-4ubuntu0.1                                 amd64        GStreamer plugin for ALSA
    ii  gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0:amd64             3.0.27-1                                          amd64        Clutter PLugin for GStreamer 1.0
    ii  gstreamer1.0-gl:amd64                      1.16.2-4ubuntu0.1                                 amd64        GStreamer plugins for GL
    ii  gstreamer1.0-gtk3:amd64                    1.16.2-1ubuntu2.1                                 amd64        GStreamer plugin for GTK+3
    ii  gstreamer1.0-libav:amd64                   1.16.2-2                                          amd64        ffmpeg plugin for GStreamer
    ii  gstreamer1.0-packagekit                    1.1.13-2ubuntu1.1                                 amd64        GStreamer plugin to install codecs using PackageKit
    ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64             1.16.2-2.1ubuntu1                                 amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "bad" set
    ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:amd64            1.16.2-4ubuntu0.1                                 amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "base" set
    ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps             1.16.2-4ubuntu0.1                                 amd64        GStreamer helper programs from the "base" set
    ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:amd64            1.16.2-1ubuntu2.1                                 amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "good" set
    ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:amd64            1.16.2-2build1                                    amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "ugly" set
    ii  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64              1.16.2-1ubuntu2.1                                 amd64        GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio
    ii  gstreamer1.0-tools                         1.16.2-2                                          amd64        Tools for use with GStreamer
    ii  gstreamer1.0-vaapi:amd64                   1.16.2-2                                          amd64        VA-API plugins for GStreamer
    ii  gstreamer1.0-x:amd64                       1.16.2-4ubuntu0.1                                 amd64        GStreamer plugins for X11 and Pango
    ii  libgstreamer-gl1.0-0:amd64                 1.16.2-4ubuntu0.1                                 amd64        GStreamer GL libraries
    ii  libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0:amd64        1.16.2-2.1ubuntu1                                 amd64        GStreamer libraries from the "bad" set
    ii  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:amd64       1.16.2-4ubuntu0.1                                 amd64        GStreamer libraries from the "base" set
    ii  libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:amd64       1.16.2-1ubuntu2.1                                 amd64        GStreamer development files for libraries from the "good" set
    ii  libgstreamer1.0-0:amd64                    1.16.2-2                                          amd64        Core GStreamer libraries and elements
$ dpkg -l | grep audio-recorder
ii  audio-recorder                             3.1.3~focal                                       amd64        Audio recorder for GNOME and Unity Desktops.
```

Comment: Can you try `sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras`? That package contains almost all media codecs.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi The deb package `ubuntu-restricted-extras` is already installed when the error appeared.

Comment: Similarly, my Rhythmbox couldn't play .m4a files but installing gstreamer1.0-libav fixed it.

Comment: @Marie My question shows that `gstreamer1.0-libav` is already installed: version `1.16.2-2` is in use. May I know which `gstreamer1.0-libav` version you are using and if you are using Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Yes, I saw that you already had it installed, I was just throwing it out there as a hint, I guess. `gstreamer1.0-libav` is version 1.16.2-2 on my install too and I'm indeed running Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: There  is a bug report that might interest you: https://bugs.launchpad.net/audio-recorder/+bug/1912876 At the very least you can reach the developer and post a new issue through the link.